# Problem with writing a Transaction with Isolation Level in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following three tables that describe a simple model for product sales:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sellers, Products, Sales;

CREATE TABLE Sellers (
    SID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name VARCHAR(256), 
    Profit DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE Products (
    PID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Name VARCHAR(256), 
    Price DECIMAL(10, 2), 
    Stock INT
);

CREATE TABLE Sales (
    SDate DATE, 
    SID INT REFERENCES Sellers(SID),
    PID INT REFERENCES Products(PID),
    PRIMARY KEY (SID, PID),
    Quantity INT
);

INSERT INTO Sellers (SID, Name, Profit) VALUES (9, 'S1', 0.0);

INSERT INTO Products (PID, Name, Price, Stock) VALUES (1, 'P1', 25, 100);
```

I now want to make the following dirty-read-proof(!) transaction:

```
START TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
UPDATE Sales SET Quantity = 10, SDate = '2022-04-07' WHERE (SID,PID) = (1,1);
UPDATE Product SET Stock = Stock - 10 WHERE PID = 1;
UPDATE Seller SET Profit = Profit + 250 WHERE SID = 1;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

However, this yields the error (in German):

> ERROR: FEHLER:  aktuelle Transaktion wurde abgebrochen, Befehle werden bis zum Ende der Transaktion ignoriert
>
> SQL state: 25P02

Here is my translation of this error message in case it helps:

> ERROR: The current transaction was cancelled, commands up to the end of the transaction are ignored.
>
> SQL state: 25P02

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `WHERE (SID,PID) = (1,1)` with `WHERE SID = 1 AND PID = 1`. When there's a syntax error, the transaction is killed, then the COMMIT explodes when execution reaches it.

Comment: @Bohemian but that is a legal syntax.  The real root problem is that the tables names are spelled differently at different places.

Comment: dirty read is possible only at 'read uncommited' isolation level according to SQL standard, but you are using 'read commied'. but even if you will start to use 'read uncommited' you would not be able to proof dirty read because in PostgreSQL 'read uncommited' drives itself like 'read commited' (https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgresql/15/transaction-iso).